# Bash/Syslog referer Address

Tags: bash, syslog

I have a syslog server, but I need to find out the URL that has been used to reach my server. For example I have syslog1.example.com and syslog2.example.com, both of which hit the same server, then in the conf file I will filter which URL was set and update a database field based on this value.
I have added fields to the database and using the conf file I am able to manipulate the request, but I need the referer URl. Does anyone have any idea how I can get this.

Obviously I have managed everything else, but have tried little towards this part of the task as I need to know if it is possible and my searches are bringing up results based on Curl which is not what I need. If anyone knows how I can get the URL, it would be most appreciated.

**Update**

I have a device which has busybox and syslogd installed. I am able to set an address on the device for the syslog, for example 1.1.1.1:514. But I am not able to do anymore on the device other than this.

I have for example 100 devices, 50 are type A and 50 are type B. The issue is that when using 1.1.1.1:514 in every device as the syslog server address, when receiving the device information on the remote syslog server I am unable to differentiate whether the device is type A or type B.

I have the following solution  in mind, although there may be another way to achieve this. If I create two subdomains and point them to the same address, ie typea.example.com and typeb.example.com, then in theory in devices with a type A I will set the remote syslog address to typea.example.com:514 and for type B, typeb.example.com:514. Both of these subdomains will point to 1.1.1.1, therefore the syslog information is now being received by devices of Type A and devices of Type B.

I need to now figure out how to in the syslog.conf on the remote server, find out whether the information was received by a device using typea.example.com or typeb.example.com.

The server does not have apache installed etc, however, in PHP for example we can use `$_SERVER` and normally I would be able to retrieve this information from, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Is there any way to do this in the syslog.conf on the remote syslog server.

As mentioned this is one solution I have in mind and it may not be the only one. Syslog is new to me and I am currently wrapping my head around this. From what I understand rather than variable or parameters, syslog uses macros. None of the macros provided seem to give me the information I need.

I know I can also set the syslog by doing say

```
syslogd -R 1.1.1.1:514
```

Is there anyway here I can include further information for example:

```
syslogd -R 1.1.1.1:514 type=a
```

Then I could say use `$TYPE` to get the value or alternatively add a custom header with the syslog.

As you can likely tell I am racking my brains for solutions and hitting brick walls. Any solution or docs that may point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Final point would be to mention I am also looking at redirecting the syslog info to a PHP script or a C (I'll say script but I know I am wrong) in order to vet the information there and then insert into the DB.

Quite simply I need a way to differentiate by type A or type B. Hopefully this clears matters up and these are not just the ramblings of a mad man.

Comment: What does a URL have to do with syslog? What syslog daemon is being used here? What are you trying to do ultimately?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am using syslog-ng to capture the syslog data. I intend to add another field to the database (as I am using a syslog-ng with mysql), based on the URL that was used by the client, I need to change this extra fields value. I can simply change the syslog url on the client and that is it. If I have two clients with multiple servers passing data to my syslog server, the URL will determine which client is which as there can be multiple ips.

Comment: The URL that was used by the client to what? What is the client? A web browser? Is syslog-ng monitoring a web server access log? Is the web server logging directly to syslog? Is the client some other program?

Comment: Ok the client has a STB using syslogd, you can set the URL of the syslog server ie url1.example.com. The domain points to our main syslog server which collects from multiple other servers. So we cannot change anything on the client side other than the url. If we set one client to use url1.example.com and the other client to use the url url2.example.com, we need some way on syslog-ng to see the URL that was used. Both the url point to say 1.1.1.1 which is the syslog server, so the data is getting to 1.1.1.1, but how did it get there. Using url2 or url2?

Comment: So that's not a URL. That's an address or domain or many other similar terms but not a URL. A URL is something like `http://stackoverflow.com`. That's why your search was getting you results for curl which aren't helpful. Anyway, if the syslog message itself (or the header/etc. is there is one) doesn't include the address of the server to which it is being sent then by the time the syslog message reaches you that information is lost. If that's the case then you need multiple IP addresses or to use the source address/domain instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner I have provided some more info that may push me closer to a solution, if you could have a read and have any input this would be greatly appreciated. Especially the section regarding adding a custom header to the syslog data as I cannot see how this is achieved.

Comment: What syslog daemon is running on the server machine? I think it should be doing dns lookups of the incoming hosts so you could use that to tell them apart if you can give the clients are DNS entries. Other then that I don't think the syslog messages themselves have any way to carry this sort of information for you. You could try finding something to do syslog forwarding which would inject a tag into the message or something for you maybe.